# How to get WH_KEYBOARD_LL to work in a Universal Windows Platform Builds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-runtime, pinvoke

Background: I have a library which requires keyboard scancodes (Not `KeyCodes` from the enum) which I am trying to get working with Unity for the HoloLens.

The only way to obtain scancodes from C# I have found so far is to use the Windows Hook system through PInvoke by registering a hook for `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` through `SetWindowsHookEx`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
                                              LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
```

Documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

The suggested way is to call it like this

```
IntPtr hHook;

using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
{
    IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook, hModule, 0);
}
```

see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex

This works well on PC builds, but the Remark for UWP in the documentation for `SetWindowsHookEx` is confusing me:

> Windows Store app development If dwThreadId is zero, then window hook
>   DLLs are not loaded in-process for the Windows Store app processes and
>   the Windows Runtime broker process unless they are installed by either
>   UIAccess processes (accessibility tools). The notification is
>   delivered on the installer's thread for these hooks:
>   WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK WH_JOURNALRECORD WH_KEYBOARD WH_KEYBOARD_LL
>   WH_MOUSE WH_MOUSE_LL This behavior is similar to what happens when
>   there is an architecture mismatch between the hook DLL and the target
>   application process, for example, when the hook DLL is 32-bit and the
>   application process 64-bit.

As I understand I have to specify `dwThreadId` on UWP, otherwise it will not work. But if I do so using `GetCurrentThreadId()` (again through pinvoke), I get an error code:

```
ERROR_GLOBAL_ONLY_HOOK
1429 (0x595)
This hook procedure can only be set globally.
```

Setting `hMod` from `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`  and `dwThreadId` to NULL creates a valid hookID but again no events arrive.

Since then I tried to search for ways to obtain a module handle, but did not find any way that works on UWP:

- `Process.GetCurrentProcess` does not compile, missing
- `Marshal.GetHINSTANCE` missing
- `GetType().Module.Name` missing (for `GetModuleHandle`)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

> The only way to obtain scancodes from C# I have found so far is to use the Windows Hook system through PInvoke by registering a hook for WH_KEYBOARD_LL through SetWindowsHookEx.

Unfortunately, the solution that you have mentioned is not applicable for UWP. For your requirement, you could use the `AcceleratorKeyActivatedevent`, and the [`AcceleratorKeyEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.AcceleratorKeyEventArgs) provides the [`ScanCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corephysicalkeystatus) value directly.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
}

private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher sender, Windows.UI.Core.AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    var scanCode = args.KeyStatus.ScanCode;
}
```